# URL routing only works in localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing

I am using URL routing and my URL works in local like this;

```
http://localhost:1545/ActivateUser/speu2mzi+TcVsO3NCQZtWAFX2lWecxotSfAOXu/1TEQ=
```

but it's not working on another host.

```
http://demo.callcenter.com/ActivateUser/speu2mzi+TcVsO3NCQZtWAFX2lWecxotSfAOXu/1TEQ=
```

my `global.asax` file:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("ActivateUser", "ActivateUser/{*code}", "~/Presentation/Site/ActivateUser.aspx");
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: you get a 404 (and not a 500)?

Comment: it produces 404 error. when I removed '+' character, it works again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [404 Error in IIS 7 when using a Url with a plus (+) sign in the path](http://www.ifinity.com.au/Blog/EntryId/60/404-Error-in-IIS-7-when-using-a-Url-with-a-plus-sign-in-the-path)

> 1) Applications that require the use of the “+” character in the URL
>   path can disable this validation by setting the allowDoubleEscaping
>   attribute in the system.webServer/security/requestFiltering
>   configuration section in the application’s web.config.  However, this
>   may make your application more vulnerable to malicious URLs:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
            <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```